# Best way to do a URL dispatcher for this situation?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-views

I'm really new to django and django rest framework and really need help on how to optimize this.
So I have this in my views.py and url.py files.

**urls.py**

```
from . import views
from django.urls import path

urlpatterns = [
    path('api/aapl/',views.aapl.as_view()),
    path('api/msft/',views.msft.as_view()),
    path('api/tsla/',views.tsla.as_view())
]
```

**views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from rest_framework import generics, viewsets
from .models import Stock, priceHistory


# Create your views here.
from .serializers import StockSerializer, PHSerializer
 

class aapl(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    a = Stock.objects.get(ticker='AAPL')
    queryset = priceHistory.objects.filter(stock = a)
    
    serializer_class = PHSerializer

    
class msft(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    a = Stock.objects.get(ticker='MSFT')
    queryset = priceHistory.objects.filter(stock = a)
    
    serializer_class = PHSerializer
    

class tsla(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    a = Stock.objects.get(ticker='TSLA')
    queryset = priceHistory.objects.filter(stock = a)
    
    serializer_class = PHSerializer
```

As you can see the aapl, msft, tsla views are basically the same thing.
I want to make it more efficient and compact by only writing 1 APIView.
I want to be able to have a path of `path('api/stock/<str:id>',views.generalstock.as_view())` but I tried a few thing but it doesn't seem to work. I don't know how to pass the id to the view and what kind of viewset to use.

How would I write out a more compact and general solution in urls.py and views.py? Thank you so much!

Comment: Did you hear about routers? https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/routers/

Comment: I did not know about routers. I will take a look at the documentation

Answer (score 1):

You can define a URL pattern that takes the item as a string:

```
from . import views
from django.urls import path

urlpatterns = [
    path('api/<str:item>/',views.PricesView.as_view()),
]
```

then in the view you can override the `get_queryset` method:

```
class PricesView(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    serializer_class = PHSerializer

    def get_queryset(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return super().get_queryset(*args, **kwargs).filter(
            stock__ticker=self.kwargs['item'].upper()
        )
```

It might however be better to work with a [*slug* [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/glossary/#term-slug).

Comment: I really appreciate your answer. I will try it out after work. Thank you so much and I appreciate your time.